# assets missing when launching/debugging Rails from RubyMine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, rake, rubymine, ubuntu-12.10

I'm trying to test an opensource Ruby on Rails site (pophealth).  I've got a VM running Ubuntu 12.10 and RubyMine.  It took a while to get all of the gems working right but they are working well now.  However, now all of the static assets that are supposed to be precompiled, are missing.

example:

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/assets/application-67beadcf527de329bd600098663ee6ca.css
```

I can see in Firebug it came back with a 404 error.  I've run rake assets:precompile several times and that works for the site fine when I run it normally under apache.  But with RubyMine working against the same root directory it doesn't like it.  I believe RubyMine is running a different web server called 'Thin'.  They only thing I can think of is that it is caching its own copy of the webroot somewhere else.  I've run find many times but I can't seem to find another local cache of the webroot.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Are you running development or production environment?

Comment: this is in a development environment, but i ran the mode as production.  I just found my problem.  I didn't have "config.assets.compile = true".  Silly Ruby n00b mistake.  :-)

Answer (score 3):

I solved it.  This was a stupid mistake on my part.  In config/environments/production.rb, I had to set config.assets.compile = true, and then repeat this for the other environments of course.